# two different variables, but one for total and one for specific user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the folowing code, in which, I get id of practice and total time of that practice according to user.

```
SELECT practice.id, SUM(practice.duration) as dur 
FROM trainingPractice 
INNER JOIN training 
ON trainingPractice.trainingId = training.id
INNER JOIN trainingStudent 
ON trainingPractice.trainingId = trainingStudent.trainingId
INNER JOIN practice 
ON trainingPractice.practiceId = practice.id
WHERE trainingStudent.studentId = '$id'
GROUP BY practice.id
```

But is it possible, that I would also get the total time of that practice? In the same query of course.

Example:

```
 id   |   dur   |   durTotal   |
-------------------------------
 23       45          240
```

Where user has been to practice 23 for 45min out of 240min

Comment: also explain how you plan to get *total time of that practice* or whatever that durTotal column in the result is supposed to be?

Comment: I'd like to get that total time (durTotal) from query

Answer (score 1):

Just add another sub query.

```
 SELECT yCQ.*, sub.durTotal   
 FROM (
        <yourCurrentQuery>
        ....
      ) yCQ
 CROSS JOIN 
     ( SELECT sum(practice.duration) as durTotal   
       FROM trainingPractice
     ) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work exactly as is because I don't know your exact table structure and relationships and I am also more used to MS SQL Server and not MySQL but it should point you to the right direction:

```
SELECT practice.id,
    SUM(practice.duration) as durTotal,
    SUM(CASE trainingStudent.studentId WHEN '$id' THEN practice.duration ELSE 0 END) as dur 
FROM trainingPractice 
INNER JOIN training 
ON trainingPractice.trainingId = training.id
INNER JOIN trainingStudent 
ON trainingPractice.trainingId = trainingStudent.trainingId
INNER JOIN practice 
ON trainingPractice.practiceId = practice.id
GROUP BY practice.id
```